# phpbb admin config file

Tags: phpbb

Does anyone know where the config file for the admin is? For instance I want to change the database connection for the admin. I know where the main config file is but is there a separate admin config file with the db connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is all contained in one config file.  Why would you want a separate database configuration for the admin that is not being used by the front end of the application?